# Python 3 remove None values from end of sublist or exclude if sublist is entirely None values

Tags: python, list, openpyxl

I have a list of lists where some of the sublists are comprised entirely of `None` and some have `None` at the end and in between strings. I need to do three things:

1. Remove the `None`s from the end of sublists if any, replacing ones in the middle which are separated by strings with empty strings.
2. Exclude sublists which are entirely `None`s
3. Create a new list of lists with the results

My attempt gets the desired results, but I am wondering if there is a faster way to do this:

```
from itertools import islice

rows = [["row 1 index 0",None,"row 1 index 2",None,None],
        [None,"row 2 index 1",None,None,None],
        [None,None,None,None,None]]
data = []

for r in rows:
    for i,c in enumerate(reversed(r)):
        if c is not None:
            data.append(["" if x is None else
                         str(x) for x in islice(r,0,len(r)-i)])
            break
print (data)
```

Desired results/output:

```
[['row 1 index 0', '', 'row 1 index 2'], ['', 'row 2 index 1']]
```

Benchmark (as best I know how):

```
from itertools import islice
import time

q = ["string",None,"string",None,"string"] + [None] * 95
rows = [q.copy() for i in range(500000)]

for z in range(1,6):
    st = time.time()
    data = []
    for r in rows:
        for i,c in enumerate(reversed(r)):
            if c is not None:
                data.append(["" if x is None else
                             str(x) for x in islice(r,0,len(r)-i)])
                break
    end = time.time()
    print ("Run: " + str(z) + "| time: " + str(end-st))
```

results (i5 ivybridge windows 10):

```
Run: 1| time: 5.787390232086182
Run: 2| time: 5.802111387252808
Run: 3| time: 5.697156190872192
Run: 4| time: 5.38789963722229
Run: 5| time: 5.739344596862793
```

Comment: its already output `[['row 1 index 0', '', 'row 1 index 2'], ['', 'row 2 index 1']]`

Comment: @Professor_Joykill they are *already using them*.

Comment: Have you considered using faster Python interpreter (like pypy)?

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a large, realistic test-set to benchmark.

Comment: @new_to_coding Actually, with the test-set you gave the relative performances changed drastically. I've added another proposed solution, that might work better in a more general case... Check out the most recent edits...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL:DR

The performance depends on the nature of the data! See the following timings, and lean towards the one that you think works better for the data-set you expect to encounter. I propose a partially in-place solution that seems to have the best performance on my tests now, but hopefully it is obvious that benchmarking needs to be fleshed out more to get a real picture of your trade-offs.

First I made a test-set.

```
In [60]: rows = [["row 1 index 0",None,"row 1 index 2",None,None],
    ...:         [None,"row 2 index 1",None,None,None],
    ...:         [None,None,None,None,None]]

In [61]: rowsbig = [r*1000 for r in rows]

In [62]: rowsbig = [list(r) for _ in range(1000) for r in rowsbig]

In [63]: sum(len(r) for r in rowsbig)
Out[63]: 15000000
```

Now, a little helper to keep things sanitary:

```
In [65]: def test_set(source=rowsbig):
     ...:     return [list(r) for r in source]
     ...:
```

So, let's wrap the three proposed approaches in functions:

```
In [86]: def new_to_coding(rows):
    ...:     data = []
    ...:     for r in rows:
    ...:         for i,c in enumerate(reversed(r)):
    ...:             if c is not None:
    ...:                 data.append(["" if x is None else
    ...:                          str(x) for x in islice(r,0,len(r)-i)])
    ...:                 break
    ...:     return data
    ...:

In [87]: def Bit(rows):
    ...:     data = [list(map(lambda x: '' if x is None else x, row)) for row in rows]
    ...:     data = [row[:max(i for i, e in enumerate(row, 1) if e is not '')] for row in data if set(row) != {''}]
    ...:     return data
    ...:

In [88]: def taras(rows):
    ...:     # remove lists with all Nones
    ...:     rows1 = [row for row in rows if set(row) != {None}]
    ...:     # remove trailing Nones
    ...:     rows2 = [dropwhile(lambda x: x is None, reversed(row)) for row in rows1]
    ...:     # replace None with ''
    ...:     rows3 = [list(reversed([x if x is not None else '' for x in row])) for row in rows2]
    ...:     return rows3
    ...:
```

And a quick sanity check:

```
In [89]: taras(test_set()) == new_to_coding(test_set())
Out[89]: True

In [90]: Bit(test_set()) == new_to_coding(test_set())
Out[90]: True
```

Now, some timing setup. Note to @new_to_coding always use the `timeit` module for creating benchmarks. There are a lot of subtleties that are ignored by a naive `time.time()` approach, as well as being more handy!

```
In [91]: from timeit import timeit

In [92]: setup = "from __main__ import new_to_coding, Bit, taras, test_set; testrows = test_set()"
```

Now, the results:

```
In [93]: # using OP's method
    ...: timeit('new_to_coding(testrows)', setup, number=5)
Out[93]: 5.416837869910523

In [94]: # using `Bit`
    ...: timeit('Bit(testrows)', setup, number=5)
Out[94]: 14.52187539380975

In [95]: # using `taras`
    ...: timeit('taras(testrows)', setup, number=5)
Out[95]: 3.7361009169835597
```

So, it seems that the incremental approach wins! Of course, the exact nature of the data may change these relative timings. I suspect that the proportion of "all `None`" rows will affect the relative performance of these approaches. **Warning! This turns out to be very true! See edit**

I've gone ahead an micro-optimized @taras approach, making sure all names are local to the function, so no global look-ups, replace `list(reversed(alist))` with `alist[::-1]`, and made the intermediate transformations generator expressions, so that only a single list is materialized:

```
In [111]: def is_None(x): return x is None
     ...:
     ...: def taras_micro_op(rows, dropwhile=dropwhile, reversed=reversed, set=set, is_None=is_None):
     ...:     # remove lists with all Nones
     ...:     rows1 = (row for row in rows if set(row) != {None})
     ...:     # remove trailing Nones
     ...:     rows2 = (dropwhile(is_None, reversed(row)) for row in rows1)
     ...:     # replace None with ''
     ...:     rows3 = [[x if x is not None else '' for x in row][::-1] for row in rows2]
     ...:     return rows3
     ...:

In [112]: taras_micro_op(test_set()) == taras(test_set())
Out[112]: True

In [113]: setup = "from __main__ import taras, taras_micro_op, test_set; testrows = test_set()"

In [114]: # using `taras`
     ...: timeit('taras(testrows)', setup, number=50)
Out[114]: 35.11660181987099

In [115]: # using `taras_micro_op`
     ...: timeit('taras_micro_op(testrows)', setup, number=50)
Out[115]: 33.70030225184746

In [116]: 33.70030225184746 / 35.11660181987099
Out[116]: 0.9596686611281929
```

Less than a 5% improvement. Indeed, I would ditch the "inlining with default arguments" and just use intermediate generator expressions, if only to help with memory efficiency.

In other words, I suggest using the following:

```
In [117]: def taras_memory_op(rows):
     ...:     # remove lists with all Nones
     ...:     rows1 = (row for row in rows if set(row) != {None})
     ...:     # remove trailing Nones
     ...:     rows2 = (dropwhile(lambda x: x is None, reversed(row)) for row in rows1)
     ...:     # replace None with ''
     ...:     rows3 = [[x if x is not None else '' for x in row][::-1] for row in rows2]
     ...:     return rows3
     ...:

In [118]: setup = "from __main__ import taras, taras_memory_op, test_set; testrows = test_set()"

In [119]: # using `taras`
     ...: timeit('taras(testrows)', setup, number=50)
Out[119]: 35.10479677491821

In [120]: # using `taras`
     ...: timeit('taras_memory_op(testrows)', setup, number=50)
Out[120]: 34.00812040804885

In [121]: 34.00812040804885/35.10479677491821
Out[121]: 0.9687599283396816
```

Since most of the already minor improvements actually come from using the generator expressions anyway!

### Edit

So, I tried it with the test set provided by the op:

```
In [3]: q = ["string",None,"string",None,"string"] + [None] * 95
   ...: rows = [q.copy() for i in range(500000)]
   ...:

In [4]: sum(len(r) for r in rows)
Out[4]: 50000000
```

Note, in my original test-set, there were about 33% "all `None`" rows. However, in the above, there are *no rows that are all `None`*. This definitely turned out to affect performance.

```
In [7]: def test_set(source=rows):
   ...:     return [list(r) for r in source]
   ...:

In [8]: setup = "from __main__ import new_to_coding, taras_memory_op, test_set; testrows = test_set()"

In [9]: # using OP's method
   ...: timeit('new_to_coding(testrows)', setup, number=5)
Out[9]: 14.014577565016225

In [10]: # using `taras`
    ...: timeit('taras_memory_op(testrows)', setup, number=5)
Out[10]: 33.28037207596935
```

So, I propose yet *another* solution. Warning! the following solution *mutates the inner lists in-place*:

```
In [14]: def sanitize(rows):
    ...:     result = []
    ...:     for row in rows:
    ...:         tail = True
    ...:         maxidx = len(row) - 1
    ...:         for i, item in enumerate(reversed(row)):
    ...:             if item is None:
    ...:                 if tail:
    ...:                     row.pop()
    ...:                 else:
    ...:                     row[maxidx - i] = ''
    ...:             else:
    ...:                 tail = False
    ...:         if row:
    ...:             result.append(row)
    ...:     return result
    ...:

In [15]: setup = "from __main__ import new_to_coding, taras_memory_op, sanitize, test_set; testrows = test_set()"

In [16]: # using `sanitize`
    ...: timeit('sanitize(testrows)', setup, number=5)
Out[16]: 8.261458976892754

In [17]: sanitize(test_set()) == new_to_coding(test_set())
Out[17]: True
```

So, using the test-set I originally made:

```
In [18]: rows = [["row 1 index 0",None,"row 1 index 2",None,None],
    ...:         [None,"row 2 index 1",None,None,None],
    ...:         [None,None,None,None,None]]

In [19]:

In [19]: rows = [r*1000 for r in rows]

In [20]: rowsbig = [list(r) for _ in range(1000) for r in rows]

In [21]: rows = rowsbig

In [22]: del rowsbig

In [23]: def test_set(source=rows):
    ...:     return [list(r) for r in source]
    ...:

In [24]: setup = "from __main__ import new_to_coding, taras_memory_op, sanitize, test_set; testrows = test_set()"

In [25]: # using `taras`
    ...: timeit('taras_memory_op(testrows)', setup, number=10)
Out[25]: 6.563127358909696

In [26]: # using OP's method
    ...: timeit('new_to_coding(testrows)', setup, number=10)
Out[26]: 10.173962660133839

In [27]: # using `sanitize`
    ...: timeit('sanitize(testrows)', setup, number=10)
Out[27]: 6.3629974271170795
```

Comment: You did a great analysis:)

Comment: this is the most extensive answer I've ever been given, I'm sorry about the poor data set I provided, but you have covered all bases

Comment: @new_to_coding yeah, sometimes I become a bit obsessive about these sorts of things... it's a pretty interesting problem. I guess when it comes down to it, mutating state tends to be a lot faster than a functional approach, especially given the performance charactersitics of python `lists`, with constant-time `.pop` operations. Plus, you can do everything in one-pass rather trivially.

Comment: Wow, very detailed analysis. I learnt a lot reading this, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can incrementally eliminate Nones with list comprehensions

```
from itertools import dropwhile

rows = [["row 1 index 0",None,"row 1 index 2",None,None],
        [None,"row 2 index 1",None,None,None],
        [None,None,None,None,None]]

# remove lists with all Nones
rows1 = [row for row in rows if set(row) != {None}]     
# remove trailing Nones
rows2 = [dropwhile(lambda x: x is None, reversed(row)) for row in rows1]
# replace None with ''
rows3 = [list(reversed([x if x is not None else '' for x in row])) for row in rows2]
print(rows3)
```

The output:

```
[['row 1 index 0', '', 'row 1 index 2'], ['', 'row 2 index 1']]
```

Comment: You can do simple timings of both methods of course.

Comment: I did some benchmarks, this does seem to be the fastest! Will update with an answer providing the methods...

Comment: should have thought of dropwhile, great suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a more compact way, but this is my take with list comprehension:

```
data = [list(map(lambda x: '' if x is None else x, row)) for row in rows]
data = [row[:max(i for i, e in enumerate(row, 1) if e is not '')] for row in data if set(row) != {''}]
```

Comment: Not sure if this is faster, it does multiple passes over the data.